# Storage partitioning redhat/centos linux; anaconda kickstart storage configuration

Tags: storage, redhat, partitioning, bootloader, lvm

Super beginner with storage related concepts. So confused with what could be the problem with the storage configuration below. This is kickstart file/string used to configure redhat os installer.

```
clearpart --all --drives=vda,vdb,vdc --disklabel gpt
bootloader --driveorder=vda
part biosboot --fstype=biosboot --size=1 --ondisk=vda
part /boot --fstype=xfs --size=256 --ondisk=vdc --label=boot
part pv.0 --fstype=lvmpv --ondisk=vda --size=1 --grow
part pv.1 --fstype=lvmpv --ondisk=vdb --size=1 --grow
volgroup awesome --pesize=4096 pv.0 pv.1 
logvol swap --vgname=awesome --fstype=swap --size=40960
logvol / --vgname=awesome -name=root --fstype=xfs --size=51200 --label=sysroot --grow --maxsize=102400
logvol /var --vgname=awesome --fstype=xfs --size=12288
# ...additional mount points...
```

So I tried to debug by only adding couple lines at a time but no luck. Usually after adding part and volgroup statements installer just throws error with no helpful info. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're doing this on RHEL 7 / CentOS 7 then your config is too far in the future. `clearpart`'s `--disklabel` option was introduced in [Fedora21](https://pykickstart.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kickstart-docs.html#clearpart) and doesn't exist in [RHEL 7](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/installation_guide/sect-kickstart-syntax), you should probably just use the `--initlabel` option. Mind you, this doesn't cause an error.

You also have a couple of other syntactical errors in the config, e.g. missing required `--name` options for the swap and /var logvol statements, plus a typo in the name option to `logvol /`. You might want to check out the ksvalidator tool that can help pick up these sorts of errors.

When these are fixed you still have some issues re. sizes: e.g. a 40960 MB (40GB) swap is likely excessive. Try the `--recommended` option that will give you a default appropriate for your system.

Below is a working version of your config where Anaconda runs to completion using the CentOS 7.1810 minimal installer image. I changed the devices and reduced the volume sizes to make them fit on my test VM.

```
clearpart --all --drives=sda,sdb,sdc --disklabel gpt
bootloader --driveorder=sda
part biosboot --fstype=biosboot --size=1 --ondisk=sda
part /boot --fstype=xfs --size=256 --ondisk=sdc --label=boot
part pv.0 --fstype=lvmpv --ondisk=sda --size=1 --grow
part pv.1 --fstype=lvmpv --ondisk=sdb --size=1 --grow
volgroup awesome --pesize=4096 pv.0 pv.1
logvol swap --vgname=awesome --fstype=swap --recommended --name=swap
logvol / --vgname=awesome --name=root --fstype=xfs --size=5120 --label=sysroot --grow --maxsize=10240
logvol /var --vgname=awesome --fstype=xfs --size=1228 --name var
```

Comment: Thanks!!!!! I got it to work; the main issue was not understanding storage concepts and the installer so the calculation for the size parameters were off... T. T